# PayPal NVP Timeout

Tags: php, api, paypal, nvp

Ok, I've bashed my head against the wall for two hours on making what I  assumed was a simple call to PayPal over NVP. I've tried everything, but it keeps telling me that it didn't work out because of an internal error that doesn't tell me what I did wrong.

O' great and wise Internet Jedi's, please guide this wayward Padawan? Thanks in advance :)

```
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-07-07T09:37:28Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => f2e28b7dcf9fb
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 53.0
    [BUILD] => 6680107
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 232.15
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

Here are the contents of the NVP call:

```
METHOD=DoDirectPayment
VERSION=53.0
PWD=1371372778
USER=xxx
SIGNATURE=xxx
PAYMENTACTION=Sale
IPADDRESS=xxx
AMT=232.15
CREDITCARDTYPE=VISA
ACCT=4111111111111111
EXPDATE=072016
FIRSTNAME=Harvey+Brooks
LASTNAME=-
STREET=3443+Padaro+Lane
CITY=Malibu
STATE=CA
COUNTRYCODE=US
CURRENCYCODE=USD
SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
CVV2=123
EMAIL=xxxx
PHONENUM=7022403735
SHIPTONAME=Some Dude
SHIPTOSTREET=90210+S+Bend
SHIPTOSTREET2=STE+120
SHIPTOCITY=Las+Vegas
SHIPTOSTATE=NV
SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
SHIPTOPHONENUM=xxx
L_NAME0=100+ANOS%C2%AE+
L_NUMBER0=19
L_QTY0=1
L_TAXAMT0=0
L_AMT0=29.69
L_NAME1=Chivas+Regal
L_NUMBER1=69
L_QTY1=2
L_TAXAMT1=0
L_AMT1=51.29
L_NAME2=Wild+Turkey
L_NUMBER2=34
L_QTY2=1
L_TAXAMT2=0
L_AMT2=29.69
L_NAME3=Patr%C3%B3n+Silver+
L_NUMBER3=23
L_QTY3=1
L_TAXAMT3=0
L_AMT3=70.19
ITEMAMT=232.15
TAXAMT=0
```

Comment: maybe stupid idea, but what if change version of API from 53 to 86? Maybe old API support version discontinued.

Comment: also, sum of your amounts is 180.86, not 232.15 (if not multiply price of second item).

Answer (score 0):

```
VISA

4066901366000455
```

cvv = 123
exp date = some future date

> $version = urlencode('51.0');

Try these setting

> $nvpStr ="&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
>             "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
>             "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

Comment: Exactly. ACCT=4111111111111111 is your problem. Unfortunately that (in)famous test card doesn't work in our Sandbox environment at the moment (I'd love to get it to work again though..)